# Is it possible to pass arguments to functions on AngularJS ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried this however it has never worked. Any particular reason why, or examples of this working? I'm thinking: `ng-click="myFunction('test')"`

Answer (score 9):

Sure, that works.

`<a ng-click="myName('jz')">Click me</a>`

Here is a simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/djYbC/1/

Comment: but how about this <a ng-click="myName({{x.id}})">Click me</a> will it work or not

Comment: There's no need for the curly braces. You are already calling an angular controller method, just pass in the argument without braces: `myName(x.id)`